# Ubertheme or Magento data migration?

Tags: magento2-migration-tool

has anybody have any experience with these two? Which one is better? 
https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-extensions-2-x/magento-2-data-migration-pro/
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/migrate/migrate-data.html

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/search?q=migration

Comment: Yes. I have experience and lot of guys here too but you need to post your problem in details.

Answer (score 2):

We used UB Data Migration Pro. It offers a great interface, so it is easy to implement. But if you have a lot of custom fields in your magento 1 enviroment then in my opinion, it is easier to implement the magento data migration.